# Creating a UISwitch that can change something in a different view

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, nsuserdefaults, uiswitch

I am creating a settings view in Xcode and Objective-C and I want it to change where a button leads in a separate view when a `UISwitch` is switched on.

In more depth the plan is if a switch is on in the settings view then 2 views down the line a button leads to view1 but if that switch is off, it leads to view2. I read something about `NSUserDefaults` but I wasn't quite sure whether it would work for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSUserDefaults can be an approach for this. You can save the state of the UISwitch as

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:switch.on forKey:@"switchState"];
```

then on button click you can check for this value

```
BOOL on = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"switchState"];
```

and decide which view it will lead to.

Hope it helps !!!

Comment: Why would you store the `BOOL` value this way? Just use `NSUserDefaults setBool:forKey:`. And read it with the `boolForKey:` method.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that by using NSUserDefaults this is a persistent value. ie. this switch value will still be saved in NSUserDefaults even when you restart the app. If this is not what you want, just save this value to memory in a manager.

You could create something like a SettingsManager that is a singleton and initialize this when you app starts and add a boolean property to save this state.

Comment: It's a setting. Why wouldn't you want it stored for the next use of the app?